# How Do I Choose A build on App Store Connect Without A Plus Button

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload an app to the app store. I have uploaded the app to apple connect but am unable to choose the build.

I did a little research and found that you are supposed to press a plus sign next to the build to choose the correct build, [but there is no plus sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5NGs.jpg).

How should I choose my build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this before when I’ve submitted builds to AppStore connect. Make sure the version number matches that of the version you are showing on your apps release/description. If this does not match you won’t be able to attach that build to that version because the App Store does not think it belongs.

You can check the “version history” tab in your App Store setup to see what the status of that version build is. When it’s done processing you will be able to add the build as long as that version matches what your preparing.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a build to app store it generally takes around 10-15 mins to process the build. You can check for the same in the Testflight tab of the itunesConnect.

Once it is processed then and then only it will be available for selecting with a plus button.

Answer (score 0):

So, either way, you need to choose the build.

Possible ways you can upload build to AppStore

1. Using XCode
2. Using Transporter

Reasons the build maybe not available in AppStore after upload

1. Your build has some issues, in this case you will get an email notification as build rejection
2. If you are uploading some build with different versions.

Comment: I downloaded the app to the transporter as well, how do I get it from the transporter to the App Store Connect?

Comment: Transporter is mac application used to upload ipa.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question for a while now and after battling with apple for a while I got the answer to this exact question. This is the response from apple

"If an earlier version of your app has the Ready for Sale status, then the list only includes builds you've uploaded since that version was released on the App Store."

Therefore, if you havent uploaded anything since the version of the app that is already ready for sale, then you will have to upload using xcode or transporter.