# Unable to upload app to app store because of a missing button on the page so i cant upload the build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am trying to upload a flutter app to the app store.
the issue is that I dont see the plus button on appstoreconnect.
I added a screenshot below

[image: Missing plus button]

this is what the button should be

[image: + is present]

After a bit of reasearch i found that there might be some version miss match([How Do I Choose A build on App Store Connect Without A Plus Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65572279/how-do-i-choose-a-build-on-app-store-connect-without-a-plus-button))

the issue that I am having is that I have cheked the version that they appear to be all the same

what is my issue?
is there a way to publish the store through xcode?

[image: version check1]

[image: version check2]

Note: i also tried updatting the build version but that didnt work[image: updated_versions]

Comment: Your Xcode screen shot shows that you are submitting *build 1.0.1* of *version 1*. You want to submit *version 1.0.1* (and build number you like as long as the build number increases each time you submit a new build for a given version)

Comment: it didnt work but thank you!!!

I added a picture of what it looks like now

Comment: Now you are submitting version 201. This still does not match the version you have in App Store Connect, which is 1.0.1. Your build will not appear in App Store Connect until the version field in Xcode reads 1.0.1.  The Xcode version and the App Store Connect version **must match**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that there was a bunch of things not configured properly.
apple send me an email listing all the things that were wrong, such as push notifications roles at stuff.

here is one of things i still need to fix::
Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "ThrAIve" 1.0.1 (18). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment' entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Best regards,

The App Store Team